# Wordpress .htaccess blocks mine?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

A very strange situation appeared.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)\.ready / [R=410,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The line `RewriteRule (.*)\.ready / [R=410,L]` is not executed until I:

- change 410 to 301 ?? (then it is working, how can this happen ?)
- remove the BEGIN WP / END WP block, if so, line is executed properly

An example URL that need a 410 code : `https://todaycycling.com/actualites-cyclisme/5t0e232502yg9t9/0002ap3_0198jqi/3613qh5786/.ready`

Comment: You may try to add this one after the WP `RewriteCond`  : `RewriteCond %{Request_URI} !^.*.ready`

Comment: Nope, it does not work :/

Comment: Sounds strange. Is there anything else in your .htaccess? You shouldn't have to remove the WordPress block, since the rules are looked at in order of appearance. Also, R=410 implies the L, but for clarity, I'd simply use G.

Comment: Yes, only that. What is disturbing me is that if I replace 410 -> 301, it does work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the default error document at the start of your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

If you have a custom 410 error document defined elsewhere in your server config then this could end up being routed by WordPress. (I've encountered some shared hosts that (for some reason) define a custom "default" ErrorDocument in the server config. If this error document does not exist then it will end up being rewritten to `index.php` and processed by WordPress.)

---

Incidentally, when you use a status code other than 3xx in the `RewriteRule` then you should simply use a hyphen (`-`) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. (It's ignored anyway.) And as @janh mentioned in comments, "`R=410` implies the `L`, but for clarity, I'd simply use `G`". So, this is better written as:

```
RewriteRule \.ready - [G]
```

To match ".ready" anywhere in the URL-path. The `(.*)` prefix is superfluous, and unnecessarily capturing the pattern is wasteful. If this should only occur at the end of the URL-path, include an end-of-string anchor (`$`). eg. `\.ready$`

Comment: You are so right ! ErrorDocument 410 default did the trick, thank you very much ! And thank you also for the regex explanation, I am a regex newbie :)